# Multiple authentication schemes with Devise and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, restful-authentication

This is probably a common question, but I haven't seen any complete answers to it anywhere:

I have an Rails 3 app that is using Devise for authentication on the web and is working fine. All actions on all controllers are authenticated and the routes are all restful. Users get redirected to a web page to enter their username and password and then can access the resources.

Now I need to add an API to the system. Most of the controllers/actions will be shared between the web and API users, but the API users will have a different authentication scheme (API keys perhaps).

So, if a web user goes to

```
/projects/1/users
```

to see the users on the web, an API user should go to

```
/api/v1/projects/1/users
```

to see the same thing with a parameter like APIKey=abcd.... either in the header or params to allow authentication.

I know the solution is around overriding the SessionController and the Routes but can't find a detailed answer about this anywhere.

Comment: Did you try out the solution below? Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes tried it. Didn't work. Given up on the whole thing and split the codebase for the API and main site.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve the same results by using Token authentication:

http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable